# Error migrating from live website to localhost

Tags: migration, localhost

I'm trying to move a Wordpress installation in a web hosting to a localhost installation for development.
I followed [this tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-live-wordpress-site-to-local-server/) (Section *Manually Move a Live WordPress Site to Local Server*, for now I'm not allowed to install plugins, so I must do it manually).

I'm using [MAMP Free edition](https://www.mamp.info/en/) and followed all the steps in the aforementioned tutorial. But when I tried to open the site in the local installation I got the message (In Safari):

> Safari cannot open the page "localhost/sitename" because cannot be connected to server "localhost"

MAMP load sites in `localhost:8888/<site-name>` so i executed:

```
UPDATE wp_options 
SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.thesite.com', 'http://localhost:8888/localsite') 
WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

where `thesite` is the name in the web hosting and `localsite` is the name of the folder in `MAMP/htdocs/` where I moved the site's files.

The only weird thing I noted is that the exported DB from the live site does not have a `home` option in `wp_options`. I don't know if it's a required row, but the online site was working without it.

What am I missing here? If I followed the tutorial correctly, it should load the site.

If you need some more info about the problem just let me know. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: In the `wp-config.php` file is that properly connected to your `localhost` database for your local WordPress site?

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan, indeed, it's properly configured (I think). I redefined the properties `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD` and `DB_HOST` as `localhost:8888` (I took the first 3 parameters from the phpmyadmin, you'll understand I cannot publish'em, trust me they are correct)

Comment: Has this question been resolved? Was my answer helpful?

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan, I've been in a rush this days and I didn't have time to try it out. I'll do it this weekend and i'll let you know. Thank you for worrying. Best regards

Comment: Just checking on your progress

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `home` and `siteurl` in your `wp_options` table is not enough unfortunately. You will still have your post content with your non-localhost URL (`http://www.thesite.com`) causing your website to not display properly on your localhost.

You should have the `wp_options` table on your localhost copy. Everything should be intact. To make sure exported your database from your live site correctly, please follow these [quick instructions provided by WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database#Quick_backup_process).

Once you've downloaded and imported your database to your localhost. Follow these steps:

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder in your **localhost** where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://localhost:8888/localsite/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. It should be pretty self-explanatory up to this point: enter your old URL in the **`search for…`** field and the new URL in the **`replace with…`** field

You can click the *dry run* button under *actions* to see what it will be replacing before you execute the script. Once you're done be sure to remove the `/replace/` folder.

Comment: It's not the only change I did in the DB, but also all the mentioned in the tutorial, i.e. in tables `wp_options`, `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`. However I'll try your solution and let you know, Best regards and thanks for your time

Comment: Ignore the tutorial that is given from the article you posted. Install a fresh copy of WordPress in your localhost, go through the setup, then replace all the tables in the database with your live site. Then follow my steps above.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work for me. For some reason, when I navigate to `localhost:8888/localsite/` Wordpress redirects me to `localhost/localsite` and I don't know why. Any other clue?

Comment: @AlvaroPedraza If you look at your `home` and `siteurl` for your WordPress install, does it include the port number? It should look like this: [image](https://i.imgur.com/uMJCqaW.png) From your question above, are you still not seeing a `home` row in your `wp_options`?

Answer (score 0):

Try This in wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```